# Deflection of radiation particles in field

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

I am studying physics at pre-University level and was studying through my textbook and I am stuck with the following query. Why are alpha particles deflected less, when going through an electric or magnetic field, than a beta particle going through the same field?

Why isn't the alpha particle, which travels at around 5% of $c_0$, deflected more than a beta particle, which travels at 98-99% of $c_0$, as it travels for a longer time through the field which therefore should cause it to be deflected more?

What is the correct reason for the deflection characteristics of radiation particles, $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: In magnetic fields, the particles will have a circular motion (if the velocity is orthogonal to the magnetic field), as the force is orthogonal to the velocity and constant in amplitude. You can find the radius ($r$) of the circle using the equation of circular motions $\sum F=ma_{cp}$ (centripetal force) where $\sum F=qvB$ (Lorentz force) and $a_{cp}=v^2/r$ (centripetal acceleration). In case of electric field both the amplitude and direction of the acceleration is constant, so to calculate the deflection, you can use the $d=t^2a/2$ formula. Just don't forget the relativistic corrections.

Comment: @fanyul this should really be more of an answer than a comment

Answer (score 1):

In magnetic fields, the particles will have a circular motion (if the velocity is orthogonal to the magnetic field), as the force is orthogonal to the velocity and constant in amplitude. You can find the radius (r) of the circle using the equation of circular motions $\sum F=ma_\textrm{cp}$ (centripetal force) where $\sum F=qvB$ (Lorentz force) and $a_\textrm{cp}=v^2/r$ (centripetal acceleration).

In case of electric field both the amplitude and direction of the acceleration is constant, so to calculate the deflection, you can use the $d=t^2a/2$ formula. If the initial velocity was not orthogonal to the electric field, it's a slightly more complicated, but thr basic idea is the same. (You can write up the equations in the same way.)

Just don't forget the relativistic corrections above about $0.1c$ (like the "relativistic mass").

Comment: Which formula is $d = \frac{t^2a}{2}$?

Comment: @EC With zero initial velocity and constant acceleration ($a$) the path/distance ($d$) can be calculated with this formula. (With constanr acceleration the velocity $v$ after a given time $t$ can be calculated as $v(t)=at$, and the average velocity for that time interval is $v(t)/2$, so $d(t)=tv(t)/2$) If there is a non zero initial velocity, than $d=v_0t+at^2/2$.

Comment: Aha, I rememeber now, it is just that I have usually seen it written as $s =  at^2 / 2$

Comment: To finish off your answer, since $s = at^2/2$, therefore $\beta$ particles will deflect more as they are travelling faster, which means they have a higher velocity and acceleration, so $s$ is greater. Is that correct?

Comment: In case of electric fields, the acceleration has nothing to do with the (initial) velocity. And actually if you do the calculations it turns out that a faster particle (**with the same mass and charge**) will be deflected less than a slower particle.